# Issue when pasting a range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a small part of the macro, I would like to move the data in range and paste it to the indicated place, and then add another date in the indicated place, but it gets wrong: How to fix it

```
With wbMe.Worksheets("input_6")
   .Range("Y26:AI26").Copy
   .Range("X26").Paste
   .Range("AJ26").Value = DateAdd("m", 1, .Range("AI26").Value)
End With
```

[image]

Comment: Remove the copy/paste lines and do it like this instead: `.Range("Y26:AI26").Copy Destination:=.Range("X26")`

Comment: braX's solution is the way to go. If you're wondering why your code is not working, it's because there is no `Range.Paste` but there is `Worksheet.Paste`. The macro-recorder would do `.Range("X26").Select` : `.Paste` (usually `ActiveSheet.Paste`) which you should never use in your code (unless there is no other way). An alternative is using `Range("X26").PasteSpecial` with many options. And another, when you only need values, is copying by assignment, in this case e.g.: `.Range("X26").Resize(1, 11).Value = .Range("Y26:AI26").Value`.